# How can azure pipeline (microsoft hosted agent) apply update on a db configured with private endpoint that allows only access within a vnet

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-virtual-network, azure-private-link

How can azure pipeline (Microsoft hosted agent) apply update on a db configured with private endpoint that allows only access within a vnet.

I created a flexible database server and secured access to it by configuring a private endpoint. As part of secure practices, I also disabled public and Azure services access. Now, I have built a script for database migration to apply to the database of the flexible server. This script will be deployed via Azure DevOps, but the trouble is that the pipeline fails to update the database, throwing network-related errors. They are keen about the security of this particular database and also want the migration script to be automated. How do I get the pipeline to apply the update without compromising security?

I enabled access to azure services on the network of the db but i do not want this solution for security reasons.

Comment: You can temporarily add the Microsoft hosted agent to your vnet and remove it once your task is performed on db.

Comment: Either allow the Microsoft's hosted agents to connect to your database, or use a self-hosted agent which has the capabilities of VNET integration and IPs under your control. The latter is my recommendation.